# How do I only allow one POST per browser session?

Tags: php, udid

How do I only allow one POST per browser session?

Comment: This seems strange. Use case?

Comment: You'll never be able to completely prevent this on the browser, so if it's important you should look into a server side solution.

Comment: Strongly suspect this is not actually a good way to solve whatever problem you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['already_posted'])) {
  echo "Already posted.";
  exit();
}

$is_valid_post = isset($_POST['txt_udid']); // && validate stuff...;

//... process $_POST....

if ($is_valid_post) {
    $_SESSION['already_posted'] = 1;
}
```

Comment: That's server-side PHP code. (The question is tagged PHP, so I figured it would be OK.) You'll need the server-side code that processes the POST to do something like that. In PHP, you use the `$_SESSION` global (after calling `session_start`) to refer to browser session data.

Comment: I don't get code that's why I have asked this question. My friend made this code for me, but he is on holiday for 6 weeks.

Comment: Hrmmmm... PHP code like this sites in different files on the web-server. Not knowing PHP means you have a high probability of screwing up the site if you change it yourself. Try to find another friend you trust who could help.

Comment: If I give you access to the site tomorrow can you do it for me?

Comment: @MuktadirMiah, it's probably not wise to offer random strangers on the Internet write access to your server.

Comment: @MuktadirMiah there are loads of tutorials on php and web development on the net.. try to learn them. u may b able to solve it by yourselves.

Answer (score 0):

save information into $_SESSION after handling submission, and at the beginning of handling submission check if any information were previously saved in $_SESSION.