# How do I only allow one POST per user?

Tags: php, javascript, udid

here is the code for adding to database:

```
<?php 
/*Config*/
```

Comment: Could you also add the code you've written for adding to the database?

Comment: Sounds like something that should be able to be easily accomplished using a [PHP session variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). Just use sessions and set a session variable (call it `posted` or something) and if that variable is set, don't allow the user to post (hide the submit button or use a PHP if-statement in your javascript to only perform the action when that variable is not set.

Comment: @Travesty3 - you should post that as an answer

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12100521/how-do-i-only-allow-one-post-per-browser-session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like something that should be able to be easily accomplished using a [PHP session variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Just use sessions and set a session variable (call it posted or something) and if that variable is set, don't allow the user to post (hide the submit button or use a PHP if-statement in your javascript to only perform the action when that variable is not set).

The session will be cleared when the user closes the browser.

As a possible example, in your PHP code for adding to the database, just put this at the beginning:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['posted']))
    die("posted");
$_SESSION['posted'] = true;
```

---

**EDIT :**

You just need to add another `else if` statement. It will look something like this:

```
if(response == "knownudid"){
    document.getElementById('udid_message').innerHTML = '<br><i><font color="red">This UDID has already been inserted and it is valid.</font></i>' ;
}else if(response == "noudid"){
    document.getElementById('udid_message').innerHTML = '<br><i><font color="orange">Please, enter your UDID.</font></i>' ;
}else if(response == "errudid"){
    document.getElementById('udid_message').innerHTML = '<br><i><font color="red">It seems this UDID is not correct. Please check for typo.</font></i>' ;
}else if(response == "validatedudid"){
    document.getElementById('udid_message').innerHTML = '<br><i><font color="green">This UDID has been found as an invalid one. Now it is valid.</font></i>' ;
}else if(response == "posted"){    // Here is the new one
    document.getElementById('udid_message').innerHTML = '<br><i><font color="red">You have already posted a UDID for this session.</font></i>' ;
}else{
    document.getElementById('udid_message').innerHTML = '<br><i><font color="green">UDID <b>'+response+'</b> successfully inserted.</font></i>';
}
```

Comment: I would have to see the code for the `insert_udid()` function. It sounds like you are calling the PHP script via AJAX. If this is the case, you will need to check the response from the PHP script and display the appropriate message to the user. Post that code and I can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

With some nice jQuery or js you could hide the form after the user submit.

Comment: That doesn't force the user to close and reopen their browser. They would just have to refresh the page.

Comment: Hmm true, php session seems more appropriate

Answer (score 0):

- Having the javascript within the HTML elements is bad, move it into the <script> tags or even better, a separate .js file.
- For HTML5 browsers, `placeholder` is a much more elegant way of providing instructions for text fields.
- If you're using AJAX to submit the form, within your function `insert_udid()` add:

.

```
document.getElementById('your_button_or_form').disabled = true;
// or document.getElementById('your_form').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

...otherwise, you'll need for the php code to disable or omit the form from the response HTML.